# Error : You do not have permission to execute this implicit payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am getting error "You do not have permission to execute this implicit payment".

I have check my app-id it is ok. Also I have tick mark box in application "Implicit payment".

Comment: Not enough info.  Are you working on the sandbox or live?  Can you paste a copy of your raw API request and the headers?

Comment: live...and sorry what you need ???

Comment: Need to see a copy of the request you're sending and double check how you have your headers setup.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by your MTS ticket that you created with our support team, the account itself is not set up for utilizing Implicit Payments. Your request has been routed to PayPal's Application Review team for approval/denial of your request to use Implicit Payments.

Comment: ok ok cory...I got your reply on that...I thought it will take more time to give response on that so i post that question here...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide an ETA, but I did email that team as well to let them know I routed your ticket to them.

Comment: is there any way for me to req. to paypal team from my side? And How can I come to know that my app is approved now?

Comment: You can update that same ticket you had with me.  Also, they should either reply through that ticket or send a message directly via your App on apps.paypal.com with their response.